# Empty cell instead null

Tags: symfony

I would like to have empty cell in my database but I always have NULL. I'm setting  'empgty_data' => '' but it's not working

```
->add('a2',IntegerType::class,array('empty_data'  => ''))
```

Thanks fro help in advance.

Comment: Could you post the doctrine annotation of 'a2' as well.

Comment: empty cell? What does that mean?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
->add('a2', IntegerType::class, array('empty_data'  => null))
```

Not sure if that will work. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

You must have defined the `a2` field as numeric and nullable and this means database will only accept numbers or null in this field. It will not accept empty string. This is a database constraint and that's a feature to keep correct type of your data. I would strongly advise you to have nulls as empty data for the numeric types. If you insist on having empty string as no value then you will have to change your mappings of `a2` to string. You might also have to change your form field type to `TextType` and provide your own validation since you'd be doing something you're not supposed to then.